# Ruby and OpenStruct allowing access to only some data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, openstruct

I have an array of OpenStruct data structures. But when I try and access them I can only access `country`

```
array = [
 #<OpenStruct country="United States", visits="202", visitBounceRate="59.900990099009896", avgTimeOnSite="151.85148514851485", newVisits="176", percentNewVisits="87.12871287128714", pageviewsPerVisit="2.9207920792079207">, 
 #<OpenStruct country="Germany", visits="155", visitBounceRate="43.87096774193549", avgTimeOnSite="167.43870967741935", newVisits="104", percentNewVisits="67.0967741935484", pageviewsPerVisit="3.935483870967742">, 
 #<OpenStruct country="Brazil", visits="105", visitBounceRate="44.761904761904766", avgTimeOnSite="227.2095238095238", newVisits="77", percentNewVisits="73.33333333333333", pageviewsPerVisit="3.5142857142857142">, 
 #<OpenStruct country="United Kingdom", visits="71", visitBounceRate="46.478873239436616", avgTimeOnSite="216.91549295774647", newVisits="36", percentNewVisits="50.70422535211267", pageviewsPerVisit="3.464788732394366">
]
```

For example

```
array.each do |openstruct|
  put openstruct.country
end
```

returns all of the countries but if i do

```
array.each do |openstruct|
  put openstruct.newVisits
end
```

lots of blank lines are returned.

Comment: how are you building them?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing special about this case. It must be something earlier in your application:

```
irb(main):002:0> require 'ostruct'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> OpenStruct.new
=> #<OpenStruct>
irb(main):004:0> os = _
=> #<OpenStruct>
irb(main):005:0> os.country = :russia
=> :russia
irb(main):006:0> os.newVisits = 60
=> 60
irb(main):007:0> os.country
=> :russia
irb(main):008:0> os.newVisits
=> 60
```

Comment: You're right. I did a `.marshal_dump` on one of the OpenStruct and the hash that it returns isn't right.